# контейнер для drawable

Tags: android

Есть иконка 13x7dp, когда ее устанавливаешь в Chip `chip.closeIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon)` она растягивается до 13х13dp т.к. контейнер для иконки квадратного размера.

Я нашел решение

icon_13dp.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
            <size android:height="13dp" android:width="13dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon" android:gravity="center">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Есть другое решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная проблема была описана в issues [на гите](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1241)

И вот какое было решение [опять же с гита](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/1242)

Теперь, используя `app:chipIconUseDrawableSize="true"`, будет использоваться размер самого drawable, а не chipIconSize.

Работает на **chipIcon** и **checkedIcon**.

*Насчет **closeIcon** - неизвестно, сам не тестировал*

Comment: Вроде ответ правильный, но у меня старая версия, и нет поддержки chipIconUseDrawableSize) И апнуть версию не могу)